# How to remove fakeraid

Tags: raid, mdadm

I had a RAID 1 setup using by bios. Ubuntu was installed on the RAID array.

I want to move to a software RAID 5 using mdadm with 3 disks. I have deactivated the RAID 1 in the bios, copied the operating system to a separate drive. 2 of the 3 disks was previously in the fakeraid.

Fdisk still shows the fakeraid and has somehow marked the raid as active. When I try to setup the RAID 5 I get an error that the first drive (sdb) is busy. dmraid does not detect any raids and does nothing.

Anybody have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to active fake RAID again and enter to its configuration page, remove RAID arrays and all its members.

If you still can't create MD array with these drives, you have to zero fill them, let the command below run about 10 minutes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1024
```